# Item explode() transition in older devices

Tags: android, android-animation, transition, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

I want a transition for a list item that opens detailsActivity. I think in 5.0 we can use

```
getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
```

Is there any way we can implement same effect in older devices?

Comment: Back to ICS you can use https://github.com/guerwan/TransitionsBackport and mimic exiting a transparent activity with a `Scene` then normally finish() the activity.

Answer (score 1):

There are few community backports for transitions:

- https://github.com/guerwan/TransitionsBackport
- https://github.com/andkulikov/transitions-everywhere

which offer you to use backported transitions. From my perspective I can recommend you Transitions Everywhere library - I applied it successfully in production code.
Unfortunatelly those backports don't support transitions between activities and fragments - you can use it only by using Scenes. They represents different layouts and you replace one by another in layout container.

Due to you scenario, probably viewgroup, where your list is placed, will be you container.

Comment: Well my listview is in a fragment and details in an Activity.

Comment: Currently you need Activity-Activity transition, what isn't possible with backport libraries. If you would like to use transition prepare layout for details and replace list with this layout inside Fragment

Comment: My app have feeds like twitter or facebook, each list item open many functions like reply,like, share etc. So I don't think using  the same fragment is not a good idea.

Comment: Twitter feed in material design that's exactly what I need.

Comment: Well, IMHO opening another Activity only for details is even worse idea. Maybe try to show Fragment with those detais above and use Fragment custom transition: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbl5cxfA1n4